# Magento Install Script won't run

Tags: php, magento, installation

I'm trying to create an install script for magento but it will not run. This is my setup

app/code/local/

- Company
- - Invoices
- - - Model
- - - - Resource
- - - - - Setup.php
- - - etc
- - - - config.xml
- - - sql
- - - - invoices_setup
- - - - - mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Invoices>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Invoices>
    </modules>  
    <global>
    <resources>
        <weblog_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Company_Invoices</module>
                <class>Company_Invoices_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </weblog_setup>
    </resources>    
    </global>
</config>
```

**mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
    die("Exit for now");
?>
```

if I rename the class in the Setup.php file it gives an error, so the folders are set up correctly. It just won't execute the install file.

Note: I checked the database and nothing is shown in the core_resource table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource node (under `global/resources`) is `weblog_setup`, yet your setup resource folder is `invoices_setup`. Make those two match and profit.

Class ref [here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L540).